# Please allow creation of the [jsreports] tag

Tags: support, status-declined, tags, tag-creation-request

For the [jsreports](https://www.jsreports.com) JavaScript reporting library, the developers indicate [here](https://www.jsreports.com/docs/designer-for-jasper-reports/#need-any-help) that they will monitor questions on Stack Overflow that are tagged with [jsreports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsreports).

But since the tag [jsreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsreport) (singular) already exists, Stack Overflow won't let me create the tag [jsreports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsreports) and advises me to use the existing tag instead.

However, the tag [jsreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsreport) refers to *another* JavaScript library, which would be quite confusing.

Please allow me (or someone else) to create the [jsreports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsreports) tag.

Comment: Just linking to SO like that doesn't really cut it though. next thing you know, there'll be bug reports for the library on here...

Comment: I think that may be what they had in mind, yes. Even so - what is the policy regarding new tags that resemble (but do not overlap with) other tags?

Comment: You can't create a tag that is just the plural form of an existing tag. (blame the developers for choosing that name). The more important problem I see is that they recommend SO as their only support platform. SO can only be used to ask about what is on-topic according to the help center. The statement on their website reads as if you should ask everything related to jsreports here. Also referring to a non-existing tag is  a terrible idea.

Comment: Sensible statement regarding the non-existant tag there. I will see if I can find any other means of contacting them. Meanwhile, sometimes the 'plural' form may well be a valid brand name :-) especially in our world of myriad libraries and projects. Oh, well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that the developers decided to astroturf their support instead of letting issues come up organically on Stack Overflow.  We can't be support for every project out there, or we're going to be beholden to these sorts of issues all the time.

I feel that someone in the Community team would need to reach out to this project.  They should look to first have their own support network, and then if users ask questions about their product here, they can deal with creating a tag then.